# proof using induction (lemma 2.2.10 of tao analysis 1)

Tags: analysis, logic

I see few answers use the same structure as the following, and am having hard time accept it as a proof
This is not the same question as the old one, I'm questioning the validity of the proof.
In short, what does it mean to prove something with induction when base case is vacaciously true?

Terrence Tao's analysis 2.2.10 lemma

show for $a!=0$ there exists unique b such that $a=b++$

you are given axioms

axiom a

> if $a++ = b++$ then $a = b$

axiom b

> $P(0)$ is true
> $P(n) -> P(n++)$
>
> then $P(n)$ is true for all natural number

The proof I saw seem to suggest the following

P(0) is true since it's of a form

> something that's can't be true -> (any T/F statement you wish to assert)

for a = 0, the LHS is false, so the P(0) is true
$$a != 0 -> a = b++ $$

we assume P(n) is true

for a = n,
$$a !=0 -> a = b++ $$

so now we attempt to prove P(n++)

for a = n++,
$$ a! = 0 -> n++ = c++ $$

We can easily do that, because from P(n) we know
$ a!=0 -> n = b++ $.

We know there exists $n$ and there exists $b++$

1. so we can say there exists $n$ by hypothesis
   2-1. $n++ = (n)++$ or $n++ = (b++)++$.

$n++ = (n)++$
So this doesn't even require n++ to be a function,
It just needs another assumption that whatever we are dealing with is equal to itself.
(Although I don't think the book listed it as an axiom).

So what we have done is,
we proved P(0) by stating vacously true statement
we assumed P(n) and assumed n exists
then proved P(n++) using the hypothesis that n exists.

I find it rather perplexing.

Cause the induction works as setting up a domino, and we have no first piece here in this proof.
I have hard time figuring out what it proved.

On regular induction proof, I can validate base(0), and construct case(1) and so on.
But here, our base case statement is..? I can't construct base.. to set up a domino..

Well I don't think you need to be able to construct the domino to show that proof worked,
I'm trying to validate it proved something and don't know any other way (well the proof itself is sound in logical terms, but when the question is  did it really prove?, I don't know other way..)

Comment: Formally the reasoning is sound.  I think what you are asking is how we are supposed to feel about it.  Perhaps it is more intuitive if we phrase it the following way: We wish to prove that every number is $0$ or a successor.   We know that $0$ is $0$ or a successor.  We know that every successor is $0$ or a successor.  Then by axiom (b) we conclude that all numbers are $0$ or a successor.

Comment: @tkf oh that is as good as I could ask for. Although my next question is that, why would I feel that way or how should I interpret my gap in believing what I saw (saw something truthful). ie. Even though I can figure out a->b is equal to a or ~b, somehow my intuition felt it were different. I guess it's not a math question but I don't know anywhere else to ask this kind of question. I guess if I apply this doubt to other stuff, I could ask how I can be sure that there's no middle ground(exclusion of middle?) for the statement I'm considering although it feels likebThanks for the great answer!

Comment: "we proved P(0) by stating vacuously true statement". Yes, property $P(n)$ is $a \ne 0 \to \exists ! b (b++ = a)$. Thus, the base case $P(0)$ is $0 \ne 0 \to \exists ! b (b++ = 0)$. As per my previous answer, we use the tautology $P \to (\lnot P \to Q)$ in the form $0=0 \to [\lnot (0=0) \to \exists ! b (b++ = 0)]$. But $0=0$ is a theorem of logic; thus, using MP we get the desired reuslt.

Comment: "we assumed P(n) and assumed n exists then proved P(n++) using the hypothesis that n exists."??? We assume the hypotheses $P(n)$ and we proved $P(n+1)$. This amounts to $P(n) \vdash P(n+1)$, from which $\vdash P(n) \to P(n+1)$.

Comment: Silly example: we have $(0=0)$ and IF we prove $(n=0) \vdash (n+1=0)$ we can use Induction to conclude $\forall n (n=0)$. What has gone wrong? The fact that we **have to prove** $(n=0) \vdash (n+1=0)$: we cannot simply state it...

Comment: "So this doesn't even require n++ to be a function,
It just needs another assumption that whatever we are dealing with is equal to itself. (Although I don't think the book listed it as an axiom)." What does it mean? $n++$ is a function "by construction" and the fact that something is equal to itself is an equality axiom that is part of underlying logic.

Comment: All the final part, starting with "I find it rather perplexing..." is out of scope.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I couldn't fit answers into a comment so I made an answer to reply to your comments. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> So this doesn't even require n++ to be a function

I didn't see the book using a function to define n++, and I thought n++ = n++ doesn't even require it to be function.
So I didn't try hard to find if the book constructed n++ as a function.

It was not a critical point of the proof, but if you can show me why its construction implies it being a function, I very much like to see it.

> we assumed P(n) and assumed n exists then proved P(n++) using the hypothesis that n exists

I was saying,
$P(n):   n!=0,  n = b++$  : here I expressed it as "assumed n exists".
$P(n+1): n++!=0, n++ = b++$ : so here I can plugin n replacing b, " using the hypothesis that n exists"

I emphasized "n exists" because I didn't think 0 was properly constructed (so not existing to me)
I guess the expression I used is not clear, sorry about that. but the proof idea seems to make sense?

> "I find it rather perplexing..." is out of scope.

I guess yes you can say that, because it's not a mathematical question.
I was saying, I can follow the statements, but I don't think I understand it.

Specifically, as I mentioned, I was not seeing the first domino constructed when I asked the question.

and tkf's comment "We wish to prove that every number is 0
or a successor." made me see the first domino piece.

Somehow I couldn't see the first domino piece being constructed with the vacuous proof.
It felt like you are constructing base case out of thin air when I do it with vacuous proof. (oh well I don't know how you will judge this comment, since it's not mathematical.. I'd like to use better expression if I could..)

I do appreciate you taking time.
I want to make clear what I wanted to convey.

Comment: See Tao, page 16: "Thus, to define the natural numbers, we will use two fundamental concepts: the zero number 0, and the *increment operation*." And see [Operation (math)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) : "In mathematics, an operation is a function..."

Comment: And see page 329: **Equality** "for the purposes of logic we require that equality obeys the following four axioms of equality:
(*Reflexive axiom*). Given any object $x$, we have $x = x$..."

Comment: Tao page 21: we can build all the other number systems, create functions.. So I thought, we are not using a concept of "function" unless he mentions it.  

Yes we need the definition of equality. But I didn't think he mentioned those. I was and I am a bit confused how hard he wants and we are supposed to be strict about what are the assumptions .. Things like should I interpret operation when he uses it at page 16 as a kind of a function are not so clear to me. Thanks for briging it up though.